# Using Stripe CLI to trigger a succeeded reporting run but getting an error regarding parameters

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe Webhooks for the Reporting API, I need to use the Stripe CLI to trigger a reporting run that has succeeded. I run the command below to do this however I get an error regarding the start `interval_start` date? How do I pass the params correctly via the Stripe CLI?

```
stripe trigger reporting.report_run.succeeded
Setting up fixture for: reporting
Running fixture for: reporting
Trigger failed: Request failed, status=400, body={
  "error": {
    "message": "Data for the report type balance.summary.1 is only available starting at 2023-12-19 00:00:00 UTC; you requested `interval_start` = 2022-01-01 14:03:52 UTC.",
    "param": "parameters.interval_start",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_3b60pLTWT1N8VN?t=1706521409",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Expected result - for it to be trigger as successfully and then this will dispatch the  webhook to confirm it has succeeded for the reporting run

Comment: One option could be to use the `--override` parameter to override the `interval_start` date to the one mentioned in the error. 

See: https://stripe.com/docs/api/reporting/report_run/create#create_reporting_report_run-parameters-interval_start

Comment: Cheers i figured it out now using that - leave that as an answer and i will accept it :)